# Go Negative LookAhead Alternative

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I was wondering if there would be any way to regex match a string that contains qcc but does not have -c following? for example the following two would match:

1. sdfsd/sdfs/d qcc -lang-c++ -Vgcc_ntoaarch64le -shared -o /dfgdfg/dfg/dfg/d -Wl  -Wl,--gc-sections /fgdfgdfg/dfgdfgd/fdgd
2. qcc -lang-c++ -Vgcc_ntoaarch64le -shared -o /dfgdfg/dfg/dfg/d -Wl  -Wl,--gc-sections /fgdfgdfg/dfgdfgd/fdgd

But the following would not:

/sdfsd/sdf/sd/fs/df/dsfds/ qcc -lang-c -Vgcc_ntoaarch64le -c  -o /sdfsd/dfsdfsd/sdfsd -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -Wformat-security -g -Os -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wno-error=format-security -DFORD_SECTION  -DFNV2LOG_DEBUG  -std=gnu11 dir.c

Comment: `(([^\-].*)|(-[^c].*))`?

Answer (score 0):

It'll never be really robust to match against option strings like this, but if you know the possible input strings (i.e. know the order of options and/or that options are never coalesced) it should be fairly straightforward. Not sure I'd bother with a regexp. You can just do this with something like:

```
if strings.Contains(s, "qcc") && !strings.Contains(s, " -c ") { do something }
```

And then you don't have to worry about the ordering of options though you do need to know that the option -c will always be presented a certain way (with spaces around for example).

Answer (score 0):

Go regex (RE2) doesn't support assertions which would have made this easy.

So, two regex conditions have to be handled separately :

1. That `gcc` exists :  `/\bgcc\b/`
2. That `-c` does not follow downstream :  `/\bgcc\b.+?\b-c\b/`

where the validation match logic is  `if #1 and not #2` then success.